# How do you bucket ranges of data in ElasticSearch?

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a repository where I have teachings that can have `0..n` devotionals, which works well for displaying summary information in my listings.  I have a single field that summarizes the number of related devotionals for this purpose.  The problem is that I want to provide a summary of facets next to the listing to allow my users to restrict the listing of teachings to just the ones that have related devotionals.

I discovered that if my aggregations are listed before my query, then the query is completely ignored.  This was very surprising to me, so I fixed my query in JSON.  I'm not sure how to enforce the proper order using NEST.

My query looks like this:

```
 {
   "size": 3,
   "sort": [ { "endDate": { "order": "desc" } } ],
   "aggs": {
     "teachers": {
      "terms": { "field": "teachings.teacher.id" }
     },
     "audio": {
       "terms": { "field": "teachings.hasAudio" }
     },
     "transcript": {
       "terms": { "field": "teachings.hasTranscript" }
    },
    "landmark": {
       "terms": { "field": "isLandmark" }
    },
    "devotionals": {
       "terms": { "field": "teachings.numberOfDevotionals" }
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the aggregations pretty much do what I want.  I can get the list of teachers, and the true/false buckets for the other items.  **The part I'm not happy with is the `"devotionals"` clause in the aggregations.**  Since the field is a count and not a boolean, I can have quite a few buckets with a `terms` aggregation and I just want to know if the teaching has *any* devotionals or not.

How do I get the document count for whether a teaching has a devotional?  I've been looking over the documentation and histograms don't quite fit my need since the buckets I need are "0" and "1 or more", not a regularly spaced interval.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on _"I discovered that if my aggregations are listed before my query, then the query is completely ignored."_?

Comment: I had a query clause that restricted the teaching documents to those that had a list of matching terms (i.e. roles of people allowed to see it), and also restricting the teacher.  When the query section was the last thing in the list, both my results and the aggregations behaved as if there was no query section.  When I put the query section before the aggregations, then the restrictions applied to both.  That was surprising to me.

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues with an example?

Comment: @RussCam, the issue is now open: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2507

Comment: thanks @BerinLoritsch

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, I don't have an answer to the question I asked using ElasticSearch.  However, I do have the following method of calculating the result I want from the response:

```
TermsAggregate hasDevotional = searchResponse.Aggs.Terms("devotionals");
int numDevotionals = (int)hasDevotional.Buckets
        .Where(b => float.Parse(b.Key) > 0)
        .Sum(b => b.DocCount);
```

A couple of notes:

- the bucket key names for number fields are always floats ("0.0", "1.0")
- the `DocCount` property is a `long`

This solution isn't pretty, and I really wanted to be able to have a count of all the documents where the `"teachings.numberOfDevotionals"` field was greater than `0` along with the actual search results.